# Combine normal distribution and Rayleigh distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, rayleigh-distribution

I am trying to find the maximum wave for a given time span based on a given measured wave height. 
In the top image the measured wave height is 2m and indicated with the black line. The probability density function is Rayleigh distributed and the red dotted line shows the p = 0.9999 location.

Now I assume that the given measured wave height is normally distributed (lower image) and I would like to find the formula for the red distribution.

How should I do this?

This is the Rayleigh probability density function I am using, where $$H = 4\cdot \sqrt{m0}$$

And the CDF is:

$$ P(\bar{H}<H) = ({1- \exp(-\frac{H^2}{8m_{0}})})^N $$

[image]